# Counting. Django query optmization, Django ORM

Tags: django, count, orm, query-optimization, django-orm

UPDATE: I FIXED THE ISSUE IN THE FOLLOWING WAY.
**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    # This query gives the totals for each degree in a dictionary, then i pass it into the view and loop over it to
    # render the values in Chart.js.
    degree_counts = Author.objects.order_by('degree').values('degree').annotate(Count('id'))

    # These query gives the manuscript totals for each volume.
    m_by_volume_count = Manuscript.objects.order_by('citation_volume').values('citation_volume').annotate(Count('id'))

    volumes = Manuscript.objects.all()

    # These query gives the manuscript totals for each section.
    section_count = Manuscript.objects.order_by('section__title').values('section__title').annotate(Count('id'))

    return render(
        request,
        template_name='index.html',
        context={
            'section_count': section_count,
            "m_by_volume_count": m_by_volume_count,
            "degree_counts": degree_counts,
            "manuscripts": volumes,
            "volumes": Volume.objects.all,
        }
    )
```

in my templates:

```
{% for b in section_count %}
{{ b.section__title }}
{% endfor %}
{% for b in section_count %}
{{ b.id__count }},
{% endfor %}
```

Can you tell me how to optimize these queries? What is the most efficient way? I want to render all values separately in a view. I attached the screenshot from django-debug-toolbar. I want to learn best practices.

[django-debug-toolbar-SQL-photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6b1h.png)

```
# These queries give the totals for each degree.

def index(request):
    authors = Author.objects.all()
    author_student_count = authors.filter(degree='Student').count()
    author_bsc_count = authors.filter(degree='BSc').count()
    author_msc_count = authors.filter(degree='MSc').count()
    author_phd_count = authors.filter(degree='PhD').count()

    # These queries give the manuscript totals for each volume.

    volumes = Manuscript.objects.all()
    volume_5 = volumes.filter(citation_volume='5').count()
    volume_4 = volumes.filter(citation_volume='4').count()
    volume_3 = volumes.filter(citation_volume='3').count()
    volume_2 = volumes.filter(citation_volume='2').count()
    volume_1 = volumes.filter(citation_volume='1').count()

    # These queries give the manuscript totals for each section.

    algology_total = volumes.filter(section__title='Algology').count()
    mycology_total = volumes.filter(section__title='Mycology').count()
    geography_total = volumes.filter(section__title='Geography').count()
    entomology_total = volumes.filter(section__title='Entomology').count()
    arachnology_total = volumes.filter(section__title='Arachnology').count()
    floristics_total = volumes.filter(section__title='Floristics').count()
    mammology_total = volumes.filter(section__title='Mammology').count()


return render(
        request,
        template_name='index.html',
        context={
            "degree_counts": degree_counts,
            "authors": authors,
            "manuscripts": volumes,
            "volumes": Volume.objects.all,
            "student_count": author_student_count,
            "bsc_count": author_bsc_count,
            "msc_count": author_msc_count,
            "phd_count": author_phd_count,
            'volume_1': volume_1,
            'volume_2': volume_2,
            'volume_3': volume_3,
            'volume_4': volume_4,
            'volume_5': volume_5,
            "algology": algology_total,
            "geography": geography_total,
            "mycology": mycology_total,
            "entomology": entomology_total,
            "arachnology": arachnology_total,
            "floristics": floristics_total,
            "mammology": mammology_total,
        }
    )
```

I tried something like this:

```
degree_counts = Author.objects.values('degree').annotate(Count('id'))
```

and got:

```html
<QuerySet [{'degree': 'Student', 'id__count': 7}, {'degree': 'BSc', 'id__count': 1}, {'degree': 'Student', 'id__count': 1}, {'degree': 'Student', 'id__count': 4}, {'degree': 'PhD', 'id__count': 1}, {'degree': 'PhD', 'id__count': 2}, {'degree': 'PhD', 'id__count': 1}, {'degree': 'PhD', 'id__count': 1}]>
```

This does not solve my problem. I as I see in the docs, this gives a dictionary rather than raw values. How would I pass these querysets in context(Where did i do it wrong)? In my HTML I have a .js chart with **data = [ {{ author_bsc_count }}, {{ author_bsc_count }}...]**

Comment: I fixed this in the following way:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think It can help you

`qs = Author.objects.values('degree').annotate(count=Count('degree'))`

next you can retrieve values from `qs`

[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: Hey, you are right, but it doesn work without order_by. So i managed to fix it with : degree_counts = Author.objects.order_by('degree').values('degree').annotate(Count('id')) Thank you !

Comment: Oh, yes, I could forgot it. Thanks.